# Триггер в Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql

Добрый день! Пробовал формировать триггер по автоматическому добавлению ключевого (инкрементного) поля в таблицу. Приведите верный пример, как используя последовательность сделать триггер с автоинкрементом числа.

Мой неверный (ошибочный) вариант ниже:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_s_before_lns () 
RETURNS trigger AS  
BEGIN 
  NEW.ns=nvl(NEW.ns,to_char(nextval('s_seq'),'99999'))
return NEW;
END; 
LANGUAGE  plpgsql;
```

Где s_seq - последовательность.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы использовать последовательности в postgres вовсе не нужно создавать триггер, достаточно указать последовательность в значении по умолчанию:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table(
    incremented_field integer DEFAULT nextval('s_seq'),
    /* ... */
);
```

Триггер на PL/SQL будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trigger_function() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
        NEW.ns := nextval('s_seq');
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Я знаю, но хотелось бы увидеть реализацию именно через триггер. Материал пока по этой теме не нарыл в интернете

Comment: Обновил ответ.